# Hibernate with PostgreSQL using default value in Entity

Tags: postgresql, hibernate

I'm developping an API using Springboot and PostgreSQL 12.
I created a user table with hibernate and the entity field that is problematic is the following:

```
@Column(columnDefinition = "BOOLEAN NOT NULL DEFAULT FALSE")
private Boolean emailVerificationStatus = false;
```

My table seems to be correctly generated :

```
create table users (
   id int8 generated by default as identity,
    email varchar(120) not null,
    email_verification_status boolean default false not null,
    email_verification_token varchar(255),
    encrypted_password varchar(255) not null,
    first_name varchar(50) not null,
    last_name varchar(50) not null,
    user_id varchar(255) not null,
    primary key (id)
)
```

My issue is while running the application I receive an error message :

```
org.hibernate.PropertyValueException: not-null property references a null or transient value : fr.mycompany.app.io.entity.UserEntity.emailVerificationStatus
```

By default, when I create the user, it sends a null value. I can solve this issue by setting the value to false in my service layer but it's not very elegant. Also, When I remove the option nullable = false, it works fine but the value is set to null instead of getting the default value. It seems that postgresql doesn't take the default value (false) as value when I try to send a user to my API. I want to force changing null value to false by default.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the hibernate [documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#schema-generation-column-default-value) you can try to use the following approach:

```java
@Entity
@DynamicInsert
public class YourEntity {

  @ColumnDefault("false")
  private Boolean emailVerificationStatus;

  // ...
}
```

Please note that the entity above is annotated with the `@DynamicInsert` annotation so that the `INSERT` statement does not include any entity attribute that does not contain a value. So, this is allow you to avoid case described in the @MikeOrganek's answer.

Answer (score 2):

You need to solve this in your service layer.

PostgreSQL is following the SQL standard.  The `default clause` value is in effect only if the column is omitted from the column list or if `default` is specified in the value list.  When Hibernate runs the `insert`, the `emailVerificationStatus` is explicitly included as `null`.

Please see:  [http://www.contrib.andrew.cmu.edu/~shadow/sql/sql1992.txt](http://www.contrib.andrew.cmu.edu/%7Eshadow/sql/sql1992.txt)

The section "<insert statement>," "General Rules," 4b, on page 389 defines insert behavior.

Comment: Right! the value was set to null by default even with setting a value....SternK solution is fine to me and fit my needs. Otherwise I would have to solve this in Service layer (what i was doing).